# Reading strings in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I would like to read a series of inputs and convert them in a `[String]`. How is that possible?

For example:

```
> Enter a string: foo
> Enter a string: bar
> Enter a string: !
> The strings you've entered are ["foo", "bar"].
```

In this case, `!` is the control character that determines the end of the input.

Comment: Why not is a real question? (sooo easy then is not?) It's a tipical problem for a rookie (my opinion).

Comment: @josejuan (Disclaimer, I didn't vote to close the Q) Yes, this is a typical problem for a newbie and there are noumeros examples all over internet with typical walkthrough, so it is not a good question here on SO. Do your homework, Be specific, Make it relevant to others, Be on-topic (see faq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
readLines :: String -> IO [String]
readLines msg = do
  putStr msg
  line <- getLine
  if line == "!"
    then return []
    else
      do
        lines <- readLines msg
        return (line:lines)
```

Use example

```
Prelude> readLines "Enter data: "
Enter data: foo
Enter data: oof
Enter data: fof
Enter data: ofo
Enter data: !
["foo","oof","fof","ofo"]
Prelude>
```

Or

```
Prelude> readLines "Enter data: " >>= (\strings -> putStrLn ("The strings you've entered are " ++ show strings))
Enter data: fofo
Enter data: ofof
Enter data: !
The strings you've entered are ["fofo","ofof"]
Prelude>
```

Or

```
main = do
    strings <- readLines "Enter data: "
    putStrLn $ "The strings you've entered are " ++ show strings
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @josejuan! I'm learning Haskell and I tried to think by myself but I couldn't find a proper solution.

As I could see you understand my problem and gave me a real nice solution: thank you!

And, unfortunatelly, I'm really sad with the reactions of the other users: StackOverflow was supposedly to be a place to post **any** question on programming, but it doesn't seem to be the point all the time. :-/

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of something similar, taken from [Real World Haskell, chapter 7](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html), which is a good resource for you.

```
main = do
   putStrLn "Greetings!  What is your name?"
   inpStr <- getLine
   putStrLn $ "Welcome to Haskell, " ++ inpStr ++ "!"
```

Now that you know how to read strings and print them, the only challenge you have is to make an array containing the two strings and print them out. Hint: Try the `show` command.

If you still need help, show us what you've tried, and include any error messages you're getting.

Comment: This example just read one input, not a continous loop, unfortunatelly. I've tried with examples, I'll post here anyway. But @josejuan already posted a solution that solve my question. Thank you for your help and advice! :)